# onclick() and multiple depending function calls

Tags: javascript

This code is what i got so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function confirmer(what) {

           var retVal = confirm("Do you want "+what+"?");
           if( retVal == true ) {
              document.write ("User wants "+what);
              return true;

           } else {return false;}

     }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="confirmer('a'); confirmer('b'); confirmer('c')" value="Result">
  </form>
```

The user should be able to choose between a, b or c. Sometimes it's only a and b (the confirmer-functions-calls are written with PHP dynamically).

The problem is: Even if the user chooses an option it calls the following function but it should break/stop/end and not asking for another confirm.

Comment: Set a flag once the user has chosen an option, and in the function, check for that flag before doing anything

Comment: This question doesn't show any attempt at solving the problem - can you provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating what you've attempted to solve the specific problem at hand?

Comment: You can change the `onclick` attribute value to an expression like this: `!confirmer('a') && !confirmer('b') && confirmer('c')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code a bit so that you only have to make a single function call. You can achieve this by hard-coding your options into your function, instead of hard-coding them in the inline HTML. For example:

```js
function confirmer() {
  console.clear();
  var options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  var option;
  while (options.length) {
    option = options.shift();
    if (confirm(`Do you want ${option}?`)) {
      console.log(`User wants ${option}`);
      return true;
    }
  }
  console.log('User does not want any option');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="confirmer()" value="Result">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the result of each method call in order to decide if you should move on to the next one.

The following is a version of your code that will do just this.

```
<input type="button" onclick="if (!confirmer('a')) { if (!confirmer('b')) { confirmer('c'); } }" value="Result">
```

If you cannot modify the output from the PHP, then you can use a global variable to prevent the other confirmations from executing.

```
var confirmed = false; // global variable

function confirmer(what) {
   if (!confirmed) {
      var confirmed = confirm("Do you want "+what+"?");
      if (confirmed) {
         document.write ("User wants "+what);
      } 
    }
}
```

Though this would require you to reset that global variable in order to run the code again without a page refresh. So your input might look something like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="confirmer('a'); confirmer('b'); confirmer('c'); confirmed=false;" value="Result">
```

Notice that `confirmed=false;` was added at the end of the code generated by PHP.